# How to Read pdf, Replace its text and Send mail using C# Web Api in .Net core project

Tags: c#, angular, pdf, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a Angular user registration form. I need send the user registered details as pdf attachment to user's registered mail address.

I already setup my smtp mail and registration forms also working as expected. All i need to do it now is above thing.

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
content.Replace("{{FirstName}}", objUser.FirstName);
content.Replace("{{ContactNumber}}", objUser.Contact);
content.Replace("{{EmailId}}", objUser.EmailId);

var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

writer.WriteLine(content);
writer.Flush();

stream.Position = 0;

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
  client.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
  client.Port = 25;

  using (var emailMessage = new MailMessage())
  {
      System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new 
      

  
System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
      var coverAttachment = new Attachment(stream, contentType);
      coverAttachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "CoverLetter.pdf";
      emailMessage.Attachments.Add(coverAttachment);

     emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(value.toemail));
                        emailMessage.CC.Add(new 
     MailAddress("My To Address"));
     emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(_configuration["Email:Email"]);
     emailMessage.Subject = value.subject;
     emailMessage.Body = message;
     emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
     emailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     emailMessage.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Default;
     emailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
     emailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(_configuration["Email:Email"])
```

Is this the right way achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution, posting here for anyone's future reference (Had to google a lot for this to connect things).

First of all I need to add **itextsharp** dll using my **nuget package manager**

And in my code

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

//To test locally and in my hosting server i used below approach
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                    {
                        path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + "Templates"
                          + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + "APPLICATION_FORM.pdf";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath
                        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + "Templates"
                          + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + "APPLICATION_FORM.pdf";
                    }

  string formFile = path;

  //Read your PDF using PDFReader
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);

  //This **Acrofields** really plucked my hair a lot, later i realized that when you create pdf file, you have option to add fields in your pdf as **FormField**. And name them as {{FirstName}}(can be any value) to replace with my actual text. Then only itextsharp will recognize those Acrofields.

  //Check your are getting this fields while debugging
  AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

  //And now you can set your fields or replace text
  fields.SetField("{{FirstName}}", objUser.FirstName);
  fields.SetField("{{LastName}}", objUser.LastName);
  fields.SetField("{{Gender}}", objUser.Gender);
  fields.SetField("{{ContactNumber}}", objUser.Contact);

  stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

  stamper.FormFlattening = true;
  stamper.Close();

  stream.Position = 0;

  //And then prepare your mail objects

  var client = new SmtpClient();

  client.Host = _configuration["GoDaddy:Host"];
  client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(_configuration["GoDaddy:Port"]);

  var emailMessage = new MailMessage();

 //Build your attachment from memory stream
 System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
 var coverAttachment = new Attachment(stream, contentType);
 coverAttachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "APPLICATION_FORM.pdf";
                    emailMessage.Attachments.Add(coverAttachment);

 emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(value.toemail));
              
 emailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(_configuration["GoDaddy:CC"]));
 emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(_configuration["GoDaddy:Email"]);
 emailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(_configuration["GoDaddy:Email"]));
 emailMessage.Subject = value.subject;
 emailMessage.Body = message;
 emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
 emailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
 emailMessage.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Default;
 emailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

 //And Finally
 client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (reader != null)
                            reader.Close();
                        stream.Dispose();
                        emailMessage.Dispose();
                        client.Dispose();
                    };

  await client.SendMailAsync(emailMessage);
  await Task.FromResult(0);
```

Phewww... that's it. I tested in my go daddy hosting space. It is working. Happy coding :)